# Convertir Imagenes Tiff en JPG/JPEG/PNG en React

Tags: reactjs, imagen

Recibo imagenes satelitales con formato `.tif` desde una api, quiero mostrarlas en un Carrusel de Bootstrap pero éste solo acepta imagenes `jpg`, `png`, `jpeg`, etc. Intenté usando la libreria `image-js` pero se me cuelga la aplicación. Me podrían dar una mano para transformar las imagenes tif?

```
    import ImageJS from 'image-js';

        export const Slider = ({siloview, setActiveImageIndex}: SliderPorps) => {
        const [listImages, setListImages] = useState<any>([]);
         
            useEffect(() => {
                siloViewList.forEach(item => {
                    //console.log("itrm", item.image_url);
                    if(item.image_url.endsWith('.tif')) {
                        console.log("termina en tif")
                    }
                });
            }, [siloViewList])
        
    const loadImage = async (imageUrl: string) => {
        const image = await ImageJS.load(imageUrl);
        return image.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    };

        return (
        <>
              <div style={{marginLeft: '2rem', marginTop: '-2rem', marginBottom: '10px'}}>
                    <span style={dateStyle}>
                           {formatDate(siloViewList[activeIndex].timestamp)}
                    </span>
                    <span style={styleImageStatus}>
                                    {imageTextStatus}
                     </span>
               </div>
                <Carousel
                  nextIcon={<ArrowForwardIosIcon style={{ color: 'black' }}/>}
                  prevIcon={<ArrowBackIosNewIcon style={{ color: 'black' }}/>}
                  indicators={false}
                  interval={null}
                  activeIndex={activeIndex} onSelect={handleSelect}
                  onChange={()=> setActiveImageIndex(activeIndex)}
                >
                   {siloViewList &&
                    siloViewList.map((img: any, key: number) => (
                        <Carousel.Item key={key}>
                            <Image
                                src={img.image_url}
                                className='slider-image'
                             />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                   ))}
               </Carousel>
         </>
   )      
}
```